# Zune Keyboard Shortcuts

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, zune, zune-software, music-management

Does anyone know what keyboard shortcuts work with the latest Zune Desktop software (I believe it is v4.7)? I am particularly interested in something which helps in navigation and search.

Also, I've noticed that if I select the leftmost column (Artists/Genres only) and start typing I get a kind of instant search. Does anyone know if -

1. there is a way to invoke this without selecting the first column
2. use it with the album and song view

Answer (score 3):

From the horse's mouth, [the Zune site itself](http://www.zune.net/en-us/products/learningcenter/zunesoftware/gettingstarted/accessshortcuts.htm) :

```
Previous item or chapter        CTRL+B
Go to search box            CTRL+E
Next item or chapter        CTRL+F
Turn shuffle on or off      CTRL+H
Eject CD (when only one CD drive)   CTRL+J
Play or pause playing       CTRL+P
Stop playing            CTRL+S
Audio playback, turn repeat on/off  CTRL+T
Zoom video size         CTRL+Z
Video : rewind video. Audio : return to normal speed.   CTRL+SHIFT+B
Fast forward through song or video  CTRL+SHIFT+F
Show Zune Help      F1
Mute sound          F7
Decrease sound volume   F8
Increase sound volume   F9
```

Comment: many of those in the first list don't work on the latest version. Did you verify them?

Comment: How can I verify them without a Zune? And you really don't have to under-vote. If you want this question to be useful to others, you might instead indicate which ones still work.

Comment: you could download it - http://www.zune.net/en-us/products/software/default.htm . as far as I can tell, only search works. Ctrl + B goes to the previous track instead of previous view. and the functionality provided by zunekeys is already provided by the multimedia keys.

Comment: I rewrote my answer with the most definitive data possible.

Comment: these are useful, but nothing on navigation or the instant search. anything on that?

Comment: Couldn't find anything on that. It might be a partial development which will be completed in some future version, which is why it isn't documented.

Comment: @Pulkit: you really expect harrymc to download a **500MB** file just to test shortcuts for an answer?

Comment: @studiohack no, but I do expect the answers posted to be atleast correct

Comment: @Pulkit Sinha: Ensuring that the answers are correct is for both of us, working as a team. We are all here just volunteers doing this as a hobby.

Answer (score 2):

**Zune keyboard shortcuts, tested and verified on  v4.8 under windows XP**

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>    =   Forward (Next track)

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>=   Back (Previous track)

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>    =   Stop

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>    =   Pause/un-pause

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> =  Goto search box (if showing on current screen, eg doesn't work in Quickplay mode)

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>    =   Toggle Shuffle mode

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>    =   Toggle Repeat mode

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> = Fast forward through a song (press again to return to normal speed)

<kbd>F8</kbd> =     Decrease volume

<kbd>F9</kbd> =     Increase volume

Answer (score 0):

I used [Google](http://www.google.com) to find [this](http://www.zune.net/en-US/support/accessibility/keyboardshortcuts.htm).

> Go to search box `CTRL+E`

Comment: what about navigation and the quick search feature?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what appears to be an undocumented trick as well - if the small progress bar on the bottom showing the current play position in the current track/video is in focus, if you hit shift+arrow keys will jump the current play position by 1 second or so. Hold the key down to rapidly fast forward - and backwards! - through the track MUCH faster than the fast forward listed above, Ctrl+Shift+F.

The tricky part is getting that little play indicator in focus. Just click the leftmost current time value to get that progress bar in focus, otherwise shift+arrow keys do nothing.